# Handle categorization as tags or hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, rest

I want to create a tree of categories and have them as flexible as possible.
Ideally those categories would be something like:

```
glasses (Contains all products)
|
|-men (Only men products)
|  |-sunglasses
|-women 
|  |-sunglasses
|  |-clear_glasses
```

My idea is that I want to use this tree to also render menu based on their relationship so a collapsing menu would be represented exactly as it appears above. This could be handy for adding, modifying or updating categories later.

My problem is that I thought about handling categories as tags like (simplified):

```
[{type: glasses},
{type: men, parent: glasses},
{type: woman, parent: glasses}]
```

The product would be:
    {prod_id: 111, categories: ["glasses", "men", "sunglasses"]}

Up to here everything could probably keep the ball rolling.
My problem is how does a system like this fit into a REST hierarchical structure?

Example I can think of:
1] - Hierarchical, while a category is a "collection" of items that are indeed of the same category I'm not sure this actually could work. 
    /products/{category}/{product_id}

2] Completely apart - Products and Categories answer as two different endpoints and they are treated as different resources altogether.

```
/categories/{category}
/products/product
```

I tried searching for similar answers but none could answer this level of specificity.